# Cluster Column Chart with each bar have different filter condition

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

In Power BI,
I want to Visualize the Cluster Column chart which is fetching the value from single Table.
Now each Bar in Cluster Column have different Filter Condition. When you choose the Particular Bar, the Filter Condition which have apply for the particular Bar for aggregation, same things should get passed in the detail table.

I have tried 4 Different Visual ( Column Chart) and 4 corresponding table against that each have different Filter conditions.

Now I have each visual(Column Chart) and each table are placed one after another, and using bookmark i am calling out corresponding visual(Column chart) and its associated table.

Now i want to have clustered Cone visual Column chart were it will have 4 cluster column in  corresponding to filtered condition i locked separetly for each column chart mentioned above. And when i select particular column as such the filter condition should passed to Table as the same as mentioned above in associated table.

In process i can optimize the Frontend and save load with multiple visual one after another.

Comment: How do you mean "have a different filter condition"? Say for the sake of argument you're creating a bar chart with Month on the axis. In that scenario, whatever measure you put on the Y-axis will already be filtered by each month. (first bar will be filtered for January, the second for February etc). Could you give an example of what you're talking about?

Comment: Lets the first Bar Visual is Giving Count of Item with Flag1=A, Second Bar is giving count of Items with Flag2=AA.
Since Field Parameter Flag 1 and Flag 2 is keep on changing, we need to get the Explicit filtering conditions are also keep changing. also after choosing the particular bar, detail table view should be updated which will show the details of items which have been included in counting.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You'd need to construct the values for the X-axis to be in a series or a table of values. So you could maybe use the VALUES() function for it. Otherwise, no clue.